# CSS property padding-top only works on the first element of a list. How do I apply to all the elements?

Tags: css, jsp, jstl, el

I am trying to apply padding to all the elements of a list but for some reason it works only on the first element. Is that how it should be? If so, how do I get the style applied to all the elements in the list?

This is the code I have currently. The 10px padding works only on the first element. I want it to be applied on all the elements in the list:

```
<c:forEach items="${list}" var="child" varStatus="status">
  <div id="${status.count}" style="padding-top: 10px;">

  </div>
</c:forEach>
```

I tried changing my above code to

```
 <c:forEach items="${list}" var="child" varStatus="status">
      <div class = "itemWithPadding">

      </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

In my css file I have the following:

```
 .itemWithPadding {
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
```

The html rendered looks like this:

```
<div class="itemWithPadding"> -stuff inside- </div> 
<div class="itemWithPadding"> -stuff inside- </div> 
<div class="itemWithPadding"> -stuff inside- </div>
```

I have of course stripped the contents inside my div tags from the html source code. But if the contents inside the `<div>` is necessary to diagnose the problem I can post it exactly the way it is rendered.

Comment: Please don't show server side code. Give us your rendered HTML code instead, and please show your CSS code.

Comment: All items have the defined padding. @see http://jsfiddle.net/VrRR9/

Comment: Can you create a http://jsfiddle.net for your problem? I cannot see a reason why this should not work. So a fiddle may help.

Comment: I created a fiddle and thank goodness I'm able to replicate the problem. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/4yFeU/

Comment: One thing I noticed in the fiddle I created is that the moment i change the padding to 500 px every child in the list is getting updated. For 100 px and below only the first child is getting affected by it. Weird!!

Comment: That's why you should post your code exactly. You stripped out the inline styles. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all the `float: left` inline styles from your `.itemWithPadding` and the `<div/>`s inside. See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E7HHC/1/).

The problem is, that block elements ignore floated children, so the `.itemWithPadding` just had the height of your `<font/>` element. The floated div inside was ignored. If you would have removed the `padding`, they would have overlapped.

Another way would be to make the outer div respect the floating content by using

```
.itemWithPadding:after {
    content: '.';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXRJa/).

By the way: You should not use `<font/>` tags. And you should consider starting with a good tutorial of how to write HTML and CSS code. Will save you much time in future.

Comment: Yes you are right about the fact I need a lot of training on HTML and CSS. Sadly I'm only doing it because there's nobody else to do it. My skill set is primarily Java and I don't really enjoy designing the user interface. However, I agree that is no reason to not learn something and thanks a ton for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a CSS class to apply your `padding-top`.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .itemWithPadding {
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
</style>

<c:forEach items="${list}" var="child" varStatus="status">
  <div id="${status.count}" class="itemWithPadding">

  </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: While this is a better solution, I would not know why it should work if the inline style doesn't. I think, something else is wrong there.

Comment: I tried this. It still only adds padding to the first element. I'll post the rendered html so that you get a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a "class" instead of "id" for padding to be applied on all the elements.

In HTML you can give same "class" to all the divs like

```
<div class="padding">
```

for all the elements you want to have same padding.

And in css give

```
.padding{padding-top:10px;}
```